# Jacobi Identity guide

Tags: combinatorics, analytic-number-theory

Can any one guide me how can I prove this identity.
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^j)^3=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(2n+1)q^{(n^2+n)/2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof of this formula, 
$$
\prod_{i\ge 1}(1-q^i)^3=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(-1)^j(2j+1)q^{\frac{j(j+1)}{2}}
$$
due to Jacobi, can be found in the paper of [Josuat-Verges and Kim](http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/~josuatv/files/josuat-jtp.pdf), section $10$, page $26$, $(56)$. It is derived from Theorem $9.1$, on page $24$.

Comment: This is the special case of Jacobi tripple product. I am not able to make this identity

Comment: I have edited it.